# Spring AOP - pointcut for loggers. @Before not triggering for logger

Tags: grails, logging, groovy, spring-aop, compile-time-weaving

I'm newbie to Spring AOP.

I've written aspect advice for all methods in my application while it throws exception.(I've tried it with grails.)

ExceptionService.groovy

```
@Aspect
public class ExceptionService {

 def logMessage(def message){
   def expInstance = new LogMessage(message:message)
   expInstance.save(flush:true)
 }

 @Pointcut("execution(* com.mypackage..* (..))")
 def allActions(){}

 @AfterThrowing(pointcut="allActions()", throwing="e")
 def allActionAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e){
   def className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName()
   logMessage(className+"\n"+e.message)
 }

 @Pointcut("execution(* org.apache.commons.logging.Log.error(..))")
 def logErrorActions(){}

 @Before(value = "logErrorActions()")
 def logErrorActionAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint){
   def className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName()
   logMessage("Error in "+className)
 }

}
```

resources.groovy

```
beans = {
 xmlns aop:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 aspectBean(com.mypackage.services.ExceptionService)
 aop.config("proxy-target-class":true) {

 }
}
```

Here, it's working fine for all exceptions `allActionAdvice()` which occurs inside application. But it's not working for `log.error(logErrorActionAdvice())`.

I researched for it on Google and it tells that the issue is with AOP and third party dependency like weaving. So, I need to do aspect weaving (compile time weaving). But I don't found any good example.

What do I need to change about my Grails application to use compile time weaving of my aspect or is there something else that I need to do?

Comment: Not sure if compile time weaving available with Groovy (others will know) but you could try using the aspects weaver as a Java agent (cmd-line arg to server) instead of rely on default cglib.